# how to use mapPartitions followed by saveAsTextFiles

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to use mapPartitions and then save the results to HDFS by the following:

```
val x = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10), 3)
x.mapPartitions(p =>  p.map( r => r+5 ) ).collect().saveAsTextFile("/path/to/folder")
```

> :29: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of
>   Array[Int]
>          x.mapPartitions(p =>  p.map( r => r+5 ) ).collect().saveAsTextFile("/path/to/folder")

It seems something is wrong but I failed to figure out what is the correct way.

THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `collect`:

```
x.mapPartitions(p =>  p.map( r => r+5 ) ).saveAsTextFile("/path/to/folder")
```

It collects data to the driver as an `Array`.